# Team Provisioning vs Ad-hoc Provisioning for ios app

Tags: xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created an ios app with xamarin cross platform template in visual studio and successfully built and run on simulator. Now I need to share my app to my client for their approval. I have enrolled for apple developer program.For provisioning and signing should I choose ad-hoc or team provisioning. I need some detailed information on team provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the AdHoc profile which should signed by your Developer account. Before creating certificate you must add Clients iPhone UDID in Member Center -> Devices. And while creating provisioning profile select client device.